# login by one user and accesstoken of another user

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have implemented simpleJWT for token based authentication. I created a simple hello world test API.

While testing, I am logging with /rest-auth/login/ and for generating use /api/token/ - both working fine.

Now for testing, I am logging in with say user XYZ (having access rights for helloworld api) and generating token using another user ABC (not having access rights for helloworld api).

So now user XYZ is authenticated (ok) but I am having token of user ABC (ok).

Now, when I call the API with token generated for use ABC, I am able to access the helloworld api even if user ABC has no rights for the API !! Because user XYZ who has rights already logged in.

Problem is this will always be case when multiple users will be using the site. How to resolve ? Few code snippets also  presented below :

My settings.py snipped

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',

    ),
}
```

code basically a decorator which authenticate for users is  as below

```
def user_is_ADM(fun_c):
    @wraps(fun_c)
    def wrapped(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # 1 = ADM
        if(request.user and request.user.is_authenticated) :   <--- here is the issue
            user_data = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id = request.user.id)

           # user profile as as a user type
            u = user_data.user_type
            if  u == 1:
                return fun_c(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                raise PermissionDenied
    return wrapped
```

what should be my strategy in this case ?

**EDIT**
Modified my decorator as follows and it is working. Someone please comment if I am doing something wrong

```
def user_is_ADM(fun_c):
    @wraps(fun_c)
    def wrapped(request, *args, **kwargs):
        juser = get_user(request)
        if juser.is_authenticated:
            user_jwt = JWTAuthentication().authenticate(Request(request))
            if user_jwt is not None:
                if request.user == user_jwt[0]:
                    k = user_jwt[0].userprofile.get_user_type_display()

                    if k == 'ADM':
                        return fun_c(request,*args,**kwargs)
                    else:
                        raise PermissionDenied
                else:
                    raise PermissionDenied
            else:
                raise PermissionDenied
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied
    return wrapped
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out this documentation https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/ (Custom permissions)

when setting a general permission setting (IsAuthenticated).
It is really authenticating users but not verifying their permissions at any time

```
class IsAuthenticated(BasePermission):
    """
    Allows access only to authenticated users.
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return bool(request.user and request.user.is_authenticated)
```

if basic administrator and user authentication is not enough. you can implement a custom permission

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class CustomerAccessPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    extracted from the documentation
    """
    message = 'Adding customers not allowed.'

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        """
        add authentication logic and return a boolean value
        """
        # ...
        # return bool()
```

in the views

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from modulename.permissions import CustomerAccessPermission

class ExampleView(APIView):
    """
    ...
    """
    permission_classes = (CustomerAccessPermission,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        """
        ...
        """
```

Here is an example with django authentication permissions

```
from typing import Tuple
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission

class CustomPermission(BasePermission):
    """
    ...
    """
    list_permissions: Tuple[str] = (
        'modelname.view_modelname',
        'modelname.add_modelname',
        'modelname.change_modelname',
        'modelname.delete_modelname',
    )

    def has_permission(self, request, view) -> bool:
        return bool(
            request.user.has_perms(self.list_permissions)
            or
            request.user and request.user.is_staff
            or
            request.user and request.user.is_superuser
        )
```

summary

With regard to the syntax in general, you will not see any changes, you must import your permission or decorator in the view, the difference lies in the runtime and the way django will evaluate the permissions

Remembering that a decorator is nothing more than a summary way of saying  func(func()).
so you should always evaluate the view and call your method modified by the decorator

instead, permissions in this framework are always defined as a list of permission classes. Before executing the main body of the view, each permission in the list is verified. If any permission verification fails, exceptions will be generated. Permission denied or exceptions. An unauthenticated exception will be generated and the main body of the view will not be executed. (Consult the documentation for a complete explanation)

You should evaluate which method is most appropriate for your case (performance, syntax, etc.).

```
# you can set your permission in the general settings to avoid importing into each file
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'modulename.permissions.CustomPermission',
    ),
    # ...
}
```

Comment: but again i have to add same modified logic as that of decorator (I have edited my question for new version of decorator) in the permission.py. What is the difference than between having decorator which validates same thing  as that of permission ? Can you please elaborate or guide/explain

Comment: updated the answer, I hope my explanation helps you.

Comment: But how to assign permissions to an user?

Comment: I recommend reading this documentation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization. It contains a good explanation and examples that you can run. users have a method to assign permissions (myuser.user_permissions.set ([permission_instances_list])). django generates default permissions per model (view, change, delete, create). You can also work at the group level (myuser.groups.set ([group_instances_list]))